# How do i fix an edittext and a send button at bottom of my List View?

Tags: android

I have a list view in which i m getting my data from server. but at the bottom i need an edit text and a send button so that its like a chat app. where i can type my message and send it back to server and it adds to my list view at the same tym.

Plz give me some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would have a look [here](http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/05/attaching-a-sticky-headerfooter-to-an-android-listview/)

Comment: Do you want those buttons to be visible always, or just when you scroll the list to the bottom?

Comment: Hey...i just put layout_weight="1" and it worked. thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make height and width of your ListView fill_parent and give it weight 1 and then below your list view add a horizontal linear layout consisting of your edit text and button

Answer (score 0):

define a xml containing a edittext and a button and set it in the list as a [footer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) like this:

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.your_footer, null, false);
list.addFooterView(footerView,null,false);
```

Comment: well...this footerView wasn't working 4 me..though putting layout weight in xml worked 4 me..